# phone regex with length validation in php

Tags: php, regex

as per the specification 
phone number should be

Alhpa-Numeric,
Space allowed,
hypen allowed,
bracket allowed,
max length = 45
can be null as well.

below is what i made using my limited knowledge and examples but its giving

> error : Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 29

My PHONE regex =

> `define('PHONE','#([a-zA-Z0-9][\s\(\)\-])*{0,45}#i');`

please guide what should i do to have all the above specification matched using regex. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex won't match what you want, with `([a-zA-Z0-9][\s\(\)\-])` each number must be followed by a space, parentheses or hyphen. to fix that make `[\s\(\)\-]` optional:

`([a-zA-Z0-9][\s\(\)\-]?)`

and use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: and how would you limit it to max length  45 ?

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz by wrapping the regex between `^` and `$` it should match null input as well: `^([a-zA-Z0-9][\s\(\)\-]?){0,45}$`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `*`. The `{0,45}` defines the number of repeats allowed.

Comment: Thanks it is working now but what would you do to allow the null as well if no phone is provided so i thought to have * there

Comment: it's 0 - 45 inclusive, so 0 times the pattern is blank, so you should be covered. Be careful though, a blank string is not necessarily the same a null.